# How can I do core dump analysis for a production application in UNIX/Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, coredump

I have come across an option to do core dump analysis by using GDB - it mentions that I need to build the executable with special command line parameters to include merging of symbols information.
But it increases the executable size, and I am guessing that it will slow down an application. 
Can someone please advice if there is another method to do core dump analysis without effecting performance of an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug symbols will not slow down the application. You can work with split debug symbols as follows.

```
gcc -ggdb -o target obj1.o obj2.o ...
strip target --only-keep-debug -o target.dbg
strip target
```

Then in gdb, use `symbol-file target.dbg`